# POST request returns 500 error, however backend works fine- angular

Tags: angular, api, post

So i'm currently trying to set up a post request to allow users to upload comments via my Angular API however, I'm getting a 500 error. I have tested the backend API POST request on postman and it works completely fine.
This is the error I'm getting: "POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/events/undefined/discussions/undefined/replies 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)"

Bellow is PostReply in the Web Service:

```
postReply(reply: any) {
    let postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('username', reply.username);
    postData.append('comment', reply.comment);

  return this.http.post(
    'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/events/' + this.eventID + '/discussions/' + this.discussionId + '/replies',
    postData
  );
```

The onSubmit function:

```
onSubmit() {
        this.webService.postReply(this.replyForm.value)
          .subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.replyForm.reset();
            this.replies = this.webService.getReplies(this.route.snapshot.params['id'],this.route.snapshot.params['_id']);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a POST request to this URL from your Angular application?

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/events/undefined/discussions/undefined/replies
```

The `undefined` is never a good thing in JavaScript. My guess is you're expecting a different route on the server than `/undefined/discussions/undefined/replies`. My guess is you have to review the way you're getting the data for the URL.

Comment: Yeah I'm not wanting it to say undefined, but am unsure why it does. Would problem be in the webSevice?

Comment: It most likely comes from where you're making the post request. 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/events/' + this.eventID + '/discussions/' + this.discussionId + '/replies'. You're most likely not retrieving the eventId and discussionId properly.

Comment: You can test it temporarily if you change the URL in the: return this.http.post(
    'YOUR URL FROM POSTMAN HERE',
    postData
  );